# Angular route animation not working when called from topbar component (Error: NG03402)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation, angular-animations

I'm trying to implement a simple animation transition between my components following the angular animations guide(https://angular.io/guide/animations). These are my animations for switching between components:

### animations.ts

```
export const slideInAnimation =
 trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* <=> DetailsPage', [
      style({ position: 'relative' }),
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%'
        })
      ], { optional: false }),
      query(':enter', [
        style({ left: '-100%' })
      ]),
      query(':leave', animateChild()),
      group([
        query(':leave', [
          animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '100%' }))
        ]),
        query(':enter', [
          animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '0%' }))
        ]),
      ]),
    ]),
    transition('* <=> *', [
      style({ position: 'relative' }),
      query(':enter, :leave', [
        style({
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: '100%'
        })
      ], { optional: false }),
      query(':enter', [
        style({ left: '-100%' })
      ]),
      query(':leave', animateChild()),
      group([
        query(':leave', [
          animate('200ms ease-out', style({ left: '100%', opacity: 0 }))
        ]),
        query(':enter', [
          animate('300ms ease-out', style({ left: '0%' }))
        ]),
        query('@*', animateChild())
      ]),
    ])
  ]);
```

The first transition switching from an unspecified component to the 'DetailsPage' component works but the second transition from an unspecified component to another doesn't. While the routing to 'DetailsPage' happens via the transitioning component itself the routing between the other components happens via a top-bar component. I suspect this is where the problem could be.

### movie.html

```
<a [title]="movie.name + ' details'" [routerLink]="['/media', movie.type, movie.id]" >
```

### top-bar.html

```
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link-active" [routerLink]="['movie']" id="movie_link_button"
             routerLinkActive="active-link" href="#" >Movie</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link-active" [routerLink]="['game']" id="game_link_button"
             routerLinkActive="active-link" href="#" >Game</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link-active" [routerLink]="['show']" id="show_link_button"
             routerLinkActive="active-link" href="#" >Show</a>
        </div>
```

When I try to trigger the animation in debug mode I get the following error multiple times:

```
Error: NG03402: Unable to process animations due to the following failed trigger transitions NG03505: @routeAnimations has failed due to: NG03014: `query(":enter")` returned zero elements. (Use `query(":enter", { optional: true })` if you wish to allow this.
```

When I add `{ optional: true }` the error message goes away, but the animation obviously still doesn't work.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I think `* <=> *` and `* <=> DetailsPage'` are conflicting. Try removing  `* <=> DetailsPage'` entirely and see what happens?

Comment: @JoosepParts I already tried that. I've also already tried explicitely switching from MoviePage <=> ShowPage but that didn't work either. Thanks for the suggestion though.